# How can I get an element to be seen by a web driver if the page is constantly refreshing?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The webpage I want to run through has a list of links to different news articles. In the script, I have the driver click the link and wait for the "h1" element to load and then check the text of that element to look for different keywords to make sure it is the correct page. However one of the news article pages fails to see the "h1" element even though it is clearly there when I inspect the page.

The page has multiple videos and advertisements that automatically play when you hit the page and my theory is that because of this it is constantly refreshing the page and doesn't give the "h1" element time to load causing the timeout. My question is is there a way that I can get this "h1" element to be seen by stopping the load or having the page wait for another element to load? I've run out of solutions. Here is the snippet of code that loops through the links.

```
 for headline in list_of_headlines:
     print "'" + headline + "'"
     art = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, headline)))
     art.click()
     driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
     title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')))
     print title.text.lower()
     if "KEYWORD".lower() in title.text.lower():
         print "Match"
     elif "KEYWORD".lower() in title.text.lower():
         print "Match"
     elif "KEYWORD".lower() in title.text.lower() or "KEYWORD".lower() in title.text.lower():
         print "Match"
     elif "KEYWORD".lower() in title.text.lower():
         print "Match"
     else:
         print "Wrong Page"

     driver.close()
     driver.switch_to_window(d.main_window)
```

Comment: in your code, you are already waiting for h1 to appear after the click

Comment: `art` is a link, when it is clicked a new tab opens with article page. So the second wait is for another window.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to interrupt page load and let me know in case of any issues:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body'))).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')))
```

Another way is to use `Firefox` + `FirefoxProfile` to set page load limit (for example, not more than `5` seconds):

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 5)
fp.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

You should also try

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.execute_script('window.stop();')
title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')))
```

but I'm not sure about this approach...

Comment: It doesn't look like any of these are working, I don't think I'm correct about why the text isn't showing. I've isolated that page in another script and printed the `title` and the `title.text` and the webelement is being found, but for some reason the text is coming up blank.

Comment: Your locator is too broad. Are you sure that you need first `h1` element on page? Maybe there is also some hidden `h1` or empty one?